# Pandas apply a function to a column while the condition is valid - deeper version

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe let's say:

```
  Product NewNetProfitMargin  Certain Value   Cost    Price
0       A       50               10              10      20
1       B       12               40              5       17
2       C       13               20              6       12
```

I would like to apply a function to the price column. Something like this :

```
def update_price(df):
  while df["New Net Profit Margin"] < df["Certain Value"]:
     df["New Price"] = df["New Total Cost"] + df["Certain Value"] * df["Purchase Price"]
     update_columns() # This function updates the profit margin and cost depended on new price.


df["Price"] = df.apply(update_price,axis=1)
```

So basically, if `new net profit margin` of a product is lower than a certain value, the function has to update the `price` until net profit margin is greater than the certain value.

---

The problem that I am facing is an infinite loop. There seems to be `df["Price"]` is not updating for each iteration. Could be because of not returning the value after calculation but I have no idea how to do it.

The actual dataset is complex but I tried to simplified. Hope it is easy to understand.

---

Here some additional details:

```
def update_columns():
  df["New Comission Amount"] = df.apply(new_commission_amount,axis=1).astype(float)
  df["New Total Cost"] = df.apply(new_total_cost,axis=1).astype(float)
  df["New Net Profit"] = df.apply(new_net_profit,axis=1).astype(float)
  df["New Net Profit Margin"] = df.apply(new_net_profit_margin,axis=1).astype(float)
  print("Columns updated succesfully!")




def new_commission_amount(df):
  
   return df['New Price'] * df['Comission Rate'] 



def new_total_cost(df):
  
  return df['Purchase Price'] + df['New Comission Amount'] + df['Shipping Cost']



def new_net_profit(df):
  return df["New Price"] - df["New Total Cost"]


def new_net_profit_margin(df):
  
  return df["New Net Profit"] / df["Purchase Price"]
```

Note: update_columns() function uses current columns and adds new results to the end of the dataframe as new columns.

**Most of the time many retailers put their prices by hand. I am trying to prevent if someone puts very low numbers, I will calculate a new price according to a rate and correct it. So they don't lose money**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because working with arrays, instead `while` set new values by mask, also for apply function for all `DataFrame` is used [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

EDIT:

```
def new_func(df):
     return df['Price'] * df['Cost'] 


def update_columns(df):
  df["New Amount"] = df.apply(new_func,axis=1).astype(float)
  print("Columns updated succesfully!")
  return df


def update_price(df):
   
    df['Price'] = df['Price']*df['Certain Value'] + df['Cost']
    # This function updates the profit margin and cost depended on new price.
    df = df.pipe(update_columns) 
    return df
```

Returned updated columns and also new columns:

```
mask =  df["New Net Profit Margin"] < df["Certain Value"]
df1 = df[mask].copy().pipe(update_price)
print (df1)
  Product  New Net Profit Margin  Certain Value  Cost  Price  New Amount
1       B                     12             40     5    685      3425.0
2       C                     13             20     6    246      1476.0
```

Add new columns filled by missing values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
  Product  New Net Profit Margin  Certain Value  Cost  Price  New Amount
0       A                     50             10    10     20         NaN
1       B                     12             40     5     17         NaN
2       C                     13             20     6     12         NaN
```

Last update by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df1)
print (df)
  Product  New Net Profit Margin  Certain Value  Cost  Price  New Amount
0       A                   50.0           10.0  10.0   20.0         NaN
1       B                   12.0           40.0   5.0  685.0      3425.0
2       C                   13.0           20.0   6.0  246.0      1476.0
```

Comment: Great tip, thanks but I got this error; `TypeError: update_columns() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given ` .  It seems because update_columns() does not taking parameter.

Comment: @MichaelAdwijk - What are inputs and output of function `update_columns` ?

Comment: It actually contains 4 different lines like this: `df["New Profit Margin"] = df.apply(update_profit_margin,axis=1)` These lines are there for updating particular column. In this case,  `update_profit_margin ` function is just returning a formula and it takes  `df ` as a parameter. Basically  `update_columns() ` function calls these lines for updating columns according to it's formula.

Comment: @MichaelAdwijk - Is possible create sample functions `update_profit_margin` and `update_columns` and add expected output if run in sample data in question? I think `update_columns` should only return something like `return column + 1` (because sample function). I ask because really hard understand how working this function, if in queston is no descritpion, only `update_columns()` - it means no input, no output :(

Comment: Sure, let me do that! I was trying to simplify but it is getting more complex. :)

Comment: I added the functions but not sure what kind of description you need.

Comment: @MichaelAdwijk - Answer was edited, create only one sample function (for simplier sample)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do both updates in 1 function like this:

```
mask  = df['Net Profit Margin']<df['Certain value']
def update_columns(df):
    df['Price'] = df['Price']*df['Certain value'] + df['Cost']
# This updates the profit margin and cost depended on new price.
    df['Net Profit Margin'] = ...
    df['Cost'] = ...
    return df
df[mask] = update_price(df[mask])
```